# Passing stl data structure to an opencl kernel

Tags: c++, stl, opencl

I'm designing a parallel algorithm where, in theory, I want to update an `std::list<...>` per thread. So say I have `m*n` threads, each of these will index a specific `std::list`, after the parallel algorithm has been executed all the list will be merged together.

There other approach I was thinking was to use a single `std::list` and lock the access when this is updated (if that's possible in openCL not entirely sure).

My question in general is... is it possible to pass stl data structure to a kernel?

Thank you

Comment: `std::list` is not designed for multi-threading. Modifying it in multiple thread at once would likely cause a runtime error.

Comment: @NO_NAME This is why I want to lock the access.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to pass standard library data structures to OpenCL in general. The memory layout of objects stored in `std::list` is not contiguous so you would have to copy your list into a buffer before passing to OpenCL.

A `std::vector` would be easier as at least its memory is contiguous but you would still need to transfer to and from an OpenCL buffer.

Comment: Since C++11 `std::vector` has method `data()` which returns it's internal array. It can be use then like any other array, including pointer arithmetic, so with a little of imagination it could be treat like a number of smaller separate arrays that just happen to be next to each other in memory.

Comment: @NO_NAME yes thats what I meant about a vector's memory being contiguous, you still need to copy to the OpenCL device though and then copy back the result of the computation unless you are using an OpenCL device with shared host memory.

Comment: What would be a suggestion then to achieve the same thing, or something similar maybe?

Comment: The thing that confuse me a bit is that I don't know a priori the size of those lists/vectors, although I guess allocating for the worst case might be ok, but each thread might insert many objects per time.

Comment: You can manage your vector dynamically as usual but at some point you will need to copy to a fixed size buffer for open CL

Answer (score 1):

There are C++ Bindings for OpenCL, [here is an example with std::vector](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/index.html#example).  It has 2 or 3 usage scenarios in the sample example (inputA, inputB, output).

I'm not seeing any bindings for stl::list and I don't expect to because of the underlying data structure.  std::vector has a continuous memory allocation for it's `data()` buffer so as far as the kernel is concerned it's just a chunk of memory.

STL vector `data()` location can change locations when adding elements.  If there is not enough room in the pre-allocated buffer, a new buffer is realloc'd with a bigger size.  This will cause problems if you are processing a vector and trying to add elements to it.  This is when you would "lock" the vector to prevent modification while your kernel is processing (or create a clone using CoR).

STL vector can take an allocator, the example contains an SVMAllocator.  This will allow you to use SVMUnMap to (presumably) upload the memory to the server (CoR).

---

As for how to structure your program... When approaching multithreading, you can start by determining Read/Write roles.  Who is a producer, who is a consumer?  Is it multi-producer/single consumer? Single producer/multi-consumer?  Single Producer/Single Consumer?

How do your kernels work?  Are they read-only on input and write-only on output? When you execute a command, is a copy of the data uploaded to the server?

How do your producers work?  Do they know the number of elements they need ahead of time?  Can you just use one big vector and provision small chunks?

Are you familiar with Map/Reduce design? Copy-On-Write? Copy-On-Read?  Concurrent Buffers? Double Buffering?

The other thing about threads is that they don't *always* have to be running. It is possible to `signal` a thread to begin work and then wait on it to finish (another `"join"` signal).  During this frame you can use a double buffered approach to produce data in the one thread and consume it in the other (i.e. upload commands). After the `"join"` you can swap the buffers.  With each thread working on it's own buffer frame, you don't need locks.  Your buffer looks something like `{ [input, output]:Frame, [input, output]:Frame }` and you just swap pointers `{ Frame*, Frame* }`.

There is also an upper limit sometimes on how many threads you can effectively use.  Sure, multicore CPUs are expanding, and GPUs have hundreds of 'threads', but unless you understand how the threads are being scheduled and interrupted *more isn't always better*.  Take for instance the difference in design between [Node.JS and Apache](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/).

I hope this gives you a lot to research/think about.  Happy coding!